# Adding 3 poll and show the total amount by adding the three together

Tags: math, asp-classic

Suppose that one has three polls in which the options are the same ...

```
Option 1 
Option 2 
Option 3
```

being that in a survey done the following result

```
POLL RESULT 1 
Option 1 - 30% 
Option 2 - 20% 
Option 3 - 50%
```

In the second poll gave the following result

```
POLL RESULT 2 
Option 1 - 33% 
Option 2 - 18% 
Option 3 - 49%
```

And third in the poll gave the following result

```
POLL RESULT 3 
Option 1 - 18% 
Option 2 - 22% 
Option 3 - 60%
```

My question is, how to make an asp in sum, taking into account all 
these three polls, and riding an average percentage over the 
results ... or ... Calculating all the polls and pointing the 
final percentage, plus all the polls.

Comment: Do you need help with the math, the code, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want ...

Average for Option 1

```
N@(30 + 33 + 18)/3
27%
```

Average for Option 2

```
N@(20 + 18 + 22)/3
20%
```

Average for Option 3

```
N@(50 + 49 + 60)/3
53%
```

Comment: This only works if each poll is of the same size. Consider the case of just two polls. Say the first was 75%/25% and the second was 50%/50%. If the first poll was 3/1 and the second was 500/500, you'd find it much different than if the first poll was 750/250 and the second was 1/1.

Comment: @mhum Of course. But that is my best guess until the OP provides more info. Also you may want to give different weights to each poll, based on another reasons, not just the sample size.

Comment: That was it, the poll will always have three options! 

It was just that, thank you.